# Mediacodec for decoding H264 stream failed to create on Nexus 6P

Tags: android, media-player, android-mediacodec

**I have an application (decoding module) which fails to create mediacodec for decoding H264 encoded stream while running on the Nexus 6P. But it perfectly works under Google PIXEL XL phone.**

I am also giving a small snap of the error I am getting while I debug it using android studio logcat. Any Help will be highly appreciated.

**Error Snap**

E/OMX-VDEC-1080P: Failed to call stream on OUTPUT due to HW_OVERLOAD

E/OMX-VDEC-1080P: empty_this_buffer_proxy failure due to HW overload

E/OMX-VDEC-1080P: ERROR: Sending OMX_ErrorInsufficientResources to Client

E/OMX-VDEC-1080P: Failed to qbuf to driver

E/ACodec: [OMX.qcom.video.decoder.avc] ERROR(0x80001000)

E/ACodec: signalError(omxError 0x80001000, internalError -2147483648)
Codec reported err 0x80001000, actionCode 0, while in state 6

E/NuPlayerDecoder: Decoder (video) reported error : 0x80001000

E/NuPlayer: received error(0x80001000) from video decoder, flushing(0), now shutting down

E/MediaPlayer: error (1, -2147479552)

E/MediaPlayer: Error (1,-2147479552)

D/EasyMovieTexture: OnError

E/NuPlayerDecoder: failed to flush OMX.qcom.video.decoder.avc (err=-38)

12-29 20:21:41.075 2737-10644/? E/NuPlayer: received error(0xffffffda) from video decoder, flushing(2), now shutting down

D/NuPlayerDriver: notifyListener_l(0xeed2aae0), (100, 1, -38), loop setting(0, 0)

E/MediaPlayer: Error (1,-38)

D/EasyMovieTexture: OnError

E/OMX-VDEC-1080P: Failed to call stream on OUTPUT

E/OMX-VDEC-1080P: empty_this_buffer_proxy failure

I guess error code -38 is coming because I want to start the mediaplayer in an incorrect state (Here as the codec is giving me an error, mediaplayer is in the ERROR state).

**I tested on Google PIXEL XL and Nexus 6P and I am getting this problem for Nexus 6P.**